# nfssvc: Address already in use

Tags: centos6, port, nfs, failed

I have installed `nfs server` using yum in my Centos 6.3 box. But I couldn't start it. Any idea?

```
# /etc/init.d/nfs start
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon:                                       [FAILED]
```

.

```
        :11:34 myserver kernel: portmap: server localhost not responding, timed out
        :11:34 myserver kernel: RPC: failed to contact portmap (errno -5).
        :12:09 myserver kernel: portmap: server localhost not responding, timed out
        :12:09 myserver kernel: RPC: failed to contact portmap (errno -5).
        :12:09 myserver nfsd[14416]: nfssvc: writting fds to kernel failed: errno 5 (Input/output error)
        :12:45 myserver kernel: portmap: server localhost not responding, timed out
        :12:45 myserver kernel: RPC: failed to contact portmap (errno -5).
        :12:45 myserver nfsd[14416]: nfssvc: writting fds to kernel failed: errno 5 (Input/output error)
        :12:45 myserver kernel: NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
        :12:45 myserver kernel: NFSD: starting 90-second grace period
        :12:45 myserver kernel: nfsd: last server has exited
        :12:45 myserver kernel: nfsd: unexporting all filesystems
        :13:20 myserver kernel: portmap: server localhost not responding, timed out
        :13:20 myserver kernel: RPC: failed to contact portmap (errno -5).
        :13:20 myserver nfsd[14416]: nfssvc: Address already in use
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

portmap was not running. I have fixed it by starting portmap.

```
/etc/init.d/portmap start
```